# как мне вывести инфу из консоли?

Tags: discord, discord-jda

короче я написал slash команду с опциями и я не пойму как мне вывести картинку из опции, я попробовал вывести инфу о картинке в консоль и потом информацию о картинке загрузить в код, но есть проблема. Я не знаю как мне вывести информацию из консоли обратно в код, помогите ее вывести обратно пожалуйста

````
    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const contracts = require("./contracts");
    
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName(`contracts`)
            .setDescription(`интерактивная команда contracts`)
            .addStringOption((option) =>
            option.setName('действие')
            .setDescription('выбери что ты сделал')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
            {
                name: `взял контракт`,
                value: `взял контракт`
            },
            {
                name: `выполнил контракт`,
                value: `выполнил контракт`
            }
            ))
            .addStringOption((option) =>
            option.setName('контракт')
            .setDescription('выбери выполненный тобой контракт')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
            {
                name: `рыбный день`,
                value: `рыбный день`
            },
            {
                name: `Свадебный банкет`,
                value: `Свадебный банкет`
            },
            {
                name: `Кабельщик`,
                value: `Кабельщик`
            },
            {
                name: `415-й, я база, ответьте`,
                value: `415-й, я база, ответьте`
            },
            {
                name: `Шахта`,
                value: `Шахта`
            }))
            .addAttachmentOption((option) =>
            option.setName('доказательства')
            .setDescription('прикрепи доказательства что ты выполнил/взял контракт')
            .setRequired(true)),
        

            run: async (client, interaction) => {
                const action = interaction.options.getString('действие');
                const contract = interaction.options.getString('контракт');
                const file = interaction.options.getAttachment('доказательства')
                const Embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(`DarkGreen`)
                .setTitle('Принято!')
                .setDescription(`**ты ${action} ${contract}**`)
                .setTimestamp()
                console.log(action)
                console.log(contract)
                console.log(file)
                await interaction.reply({embeds: [Embed1],
                ephemeral: true    
            });

            const Embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(`DarkGreen`)
            .setTitle('Информация о контракте!')
            .setDescription(`**игрок ${action} ${contract}**`)
            .setTimestamp()
            interaction.followUp({
              embeds: [Embed2],
              files: []
            });
                }
                }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить картинку, используя метод setImage (также можно использовать setThumbnail, в таком случае изображение будет другого вида) объекта EmbedBuilder.

В вашем случае, как мне кажется, вам следует добавить следующую строку:

```js
.setImage(file.url)
```

"Вывести информацию из консоли обратно в код" вы можете, скопировав информацию из консоли и вставив ее в код.

Comment: да сработало, спасибо